# How do I create an eventlog event upon a SQL connectivity issue? Here's my concrete example:

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to connect to an external database and the connectivity may sometimes fail. However, I am seeing that if the SELECT statement below fails, the IF statement after that does not execute at all:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DB].[View] 
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
  EXEC xp_logevent 63000, 'Issue!', error
END
```

Here's the error message:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   Could not use view or function 'DB.view' because of binding errors.
>
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Servers2Switchs, Line 60
>   Invalid object name xxx.

Comment: If you can't connect to the database then it can't run your `IF` statement. Your exception handling must be done in the application that you're using to try to connect.

Comment: "I need to connect to an external database and the connectivity may sometimes fail."  Doesn't that imply that there are two databases here and we can hope xp_logevent is on the one calling the db.view (external?)

Comment: Looking further at your code and the returned error message, I'm guessing that this is an issue with a linked server. Can you please provide more details as to exactly what you're trying to do and when you are seeing the error?

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses.
- To provide more background information, I am connecting to the local database instance and using a linked server connection to [DB].[view]
- I am able to connect to my local SQL instance just fine. It is the connection to [DB].[view] that sometimes fails (the owner of that system sometimes inadvertently changes permissions for my service account)